# C program crashes sometimes and sometimes not

Tags: c

I'm only a few days into C programming. I wanted to rewrite a small program for computing prime numbers in C to see how much faster it would run in comparison to Java (the programming language I'm coming from).

I now encountered a (to me) very strange problem. Sometimes the program works fine, compiles and terminates, but sometimes it crashes somewhere in the "calculateNewPrimes()" function. Eclipse doesn't display any error-messages and the compilation seems also to work fine. Does anybody see the mistake and could point it out for a c-newbie like me? :) Previous research on this site and other web-pages didn't brought any result.

Global variables:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void prepareSession();
void calculateNewPrimes();
void saveResults();

// you can modify the filepath here if you're on a new machine
char filePath[] = "/home/userName/Eclipse/workspace/PrimeNumbers/primes.txt";

// the available system memory or the maxAmount of memory you would like
// to use for the storage of the prime-numbers in BYTES
long long int memorySize = 7000000000LL;

//The file where the prime numbers will be saved
FILE *file;

// We begin with the number 3, so that we only have to check odd numbers.
// 2 is therefore already discovered (amount = 1)
long long int oldAmount = 1;
long long int current = 3;

// a pointer to the array with the already known primes
long long int *knownPrimes;
long long int *newPrimes;
```

The program consists of 3 functions. The first one reads primes from previous calculations in the memory, the second one calculates the new primes and the last function saves the newly calculated primes back into the file.

```
int main(){
    prepareSession();
    calculateNewPrimes();
    saveResults();
}
```

The function prepareSession() seems to work just fine. You can assume that the file doesn't exist yet and the start conditions are used.

```
void prepareSession(){
    // try to open the file, if the file doesn't exist it will be created
    file = fopen(filePath,"a+");
    long long int temp = -1;
    fscanf(file,"%lli",&temp);
    // if the file isn't empty, read the amount and the highest number in their variables
    if(temp != -1){
        /*some code */
    }
    else{
        // the file was newly created so the only known prime is 2
        printf("File doesn't yet exist. \n");
        long long int temp[1] = {2};
        knownPrimes = temp;
    }
    fclose (file);
}
```

The critical function. Somewhere here the error occurs.

```
void calculateNewPrimes(){
        long long int newAmount;
        long long int primesFound = 0;

        printf("How many new primes would you like to calculate? \n");
        scanf("%lli",&newAmount);
        printf("I will calculate %lli new primes. \n",newAmount);
        long long int temp[newAmount];
        newPrimes = temp;

        //prepare measuring
        double progress=0.0;
        int oldProgress=0;
        time_t start = time(0);

        long long int currentNumber,oldNumber;
        // start the calculations
        while(primesFound < newAmount){
            oldNumber = 2;
            for(long long int i = 1; i < oldAmount + newAmount; i++){
                if(i < oldAmount){currentNumber = *(knownPrimes + i);}
                else{ currentNumber = *(newPrimes + (i-oldAmount));}

                if(current % currentNumber == 0){
                    break;
                }
                else if(currentNumber > current/oldNumber || i == oldAmount + primesFound-1){
                    *(newPrimes + primesFound++) = current;
                    printf("Found Nr.%lli: %lli \n",primesFound,current);
                    progress = (primesFound)/(double) newAmount;
                    while(oldProgress/100.0 < progress){
                            printf("%d \n",++oldProgress);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            current+=2;
        }
        double timeDifference = difftime( time(0), start);
        printf("It took %g to calculate %lli new Primes \n",timeDifference, newAmount);
    }
```

Comment: Does it crash, or does it hang? The title seems to contradict the body.

Comment: And what debugging have you done? Where does it get stuck **exactly** / what is the error it crashes with?

Comment: random crashes usually come from accessing unitialized/freed memory

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], instead of a code puzzle.

Comment: `newPrimes` is global variable and `temp` is local to the fucntion `calculateNewPrimes` and in the function  you do `long long int temp[newAmount]; newPrimes = temp;`. This clearly causes undefined behaviour when you access `newPrimes` later in the program. To overcome this you can use `malloc` or `calloc`. There can be several other errors like this and the one mentioned in one of the comments. You can look for them.

Comment: `long long int temp[1] = {2};` this is in automatic storage. You point a *global* pointer to this.

Comment: Your `temp` arrays *cease to exist* when their enclosing functions exit, rendering your `newPrimes` and `knownPrimes` pointers *invalid*.  You're hip deep in undefined behavior territory here.

Comment: Get rid of the global variables in the first place. They are likely the source of many bugs here.

Comment: `long long int temp[newAmount];` Don't use automatic VLAs, they will crash your program.

Comment: `void prepareSession();` etc. are invalid declarators. Use a prototype: `void prepareSession(void);` etc.

Comment: "to see how much faster it would run in comparison to Java" - All this just to see how fast C is?

Answer (score 1):

OK, a few pointers to get started here.

You say, "it seems to get stuck", sometimes.  Let's break this down:

1. Do you mean the program hangs?  How do you know it is in this
   function?  Have you broken into the debugger?
2. Does the "sometimes" have any relationship to the input?  Or is it random?  "Input" would include both the file and the number you input.
3. Does the program ever crash?

**Suggestion #1:** If the program hangs, you should be able to break into it in the debugger, and then step through the code to see where it is going wrong.  Otherwise, some print statements in key places can give you debugging hints.

Now to the code itself.

1. You have a clear bug in the code as mentioned in – [GAURANG VYAS's   comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44906261/c-program-crashes-sometimes-and-sometimes-not#comment76789674_44906261)
   .  You are referencing a local variable through a global
   pointer (`temp`) after the function has exited.   This alone could
   cause inconsistent behaviour, crashes, etc.
2. You've got an `else if` with a somewhat complex condition.  If you aren't a whiz in C operator precedence, you may or may not be doing what you think you are.  (Even if you have it right, the next person reading the code may not!).  I suggest using parentheses.
3. OK, I copied, compiled, and ran your code.  You are going into an infinite loop, and it does seem to be related to the number you input.  `5` always seems to work, `6` does not.  This is a useful clue; your conditions to exit the loop are failing when the number gets larger. Again, since you are referencing freed memory you may be using invalid data here.

Try adding the line - 
 
`printf("current is %d\n", current);` immediately after `current+=2;`
and you will see that you are in an infinite loop; it just keeps increasing.

This is hopefully enough information for you to continue the debugging.

Comment: Perhaps.  Considering the form of the question though, I thought this was a reasonable kind of answer.  You are free to disagree :-) and might be right though...

Comment: Thank you Gaurang Vyas for the edits.  I see I have a lot to learn about how to write and format an answer here!